# Calling oracle function with custom type return value from c#

Tags: c#, oracle, pipeline

I have custom oracle data type:

```
type tClients is record(
    id        NUMBER,
    name    VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR),
    tax    varchar2(30),
    IsClient      number
);

type tTClients is table of tClients;
```

and oracle function with return value of tTClients pipelined:

```
function getClients(p_Organization_Name  varchar2,
                          p_Director_Last_Name varchar2,
                         ) return tTClients
        pipelined;
```

I use ODP.NET and try next code in C#:

```
using(OracleConnection conOra=new OracleConnection(oraConStr))
            {
                conOra.Open();
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MQ_CRM.CC_NEW.getClients",conOra))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Organization_Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "мяскин", ParameterDirection.Input));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Director_Last_Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2,"", ParameterDirection.Input));
                 //return parameter
                    OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter();
                    p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
                    p.UdtTypeName = "MQ_CRM.CC_NEW.tTClients";
                    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);


                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Have exception ORA-06550. Execute this function directly sqlplus work fine.
How can i solve this problem&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use custom types in ODP.NET directly. However, you can use it as

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conOra;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE(MQ_CRM.CC_NEW.getClients(:p_Organization_Name, :p_Director_Last_Name)) ";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Organization_Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "мяскин", ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Director_Last_Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2,"", ParameterDirection.Input));
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

In case you like to get back a `OracleDbType.RefCursor` then your function must return SYS_REFCURSOR type, see [Using PL/SQL Stored Procedures and REF CURSORs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_plsql.htm#TDPNG60000) and [Cursor Variable Declaratio](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_variable.htm#LNPLS01312)n

Comment: Thx. Now I do this. This good workaround, but I think right way is use CommandType.StoredProcedure and get return value after execution.